# JQuery Change Class With Animate

Tags: jquery

I am making a side menu that pops out when you click the tab. I have come to the point where I do not know how to continue on, I need the class on the tab div to change to "sideopen" when it is clicked. I have tried `attr();` and I also tried `removeClass();` and `addClass();` but to no avail.

Here is the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bGKvR/

Also, I am a newbie to JS/JQuery so any advice to cleaning the code up is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem that the classes aren't being added/removed properly, or that the elements keep moving to the right upon repeated clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked over it but you should consider learning basic programming.

```
$(".sideclosed").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('#sidepanel, #sidepaneltab').animate({
    left: ($this.hasClass("open") ? '-' : '+') + '=200' // if it should open use '+' else use '-'
  }, 1000);
  // now toggle open class
  $this.toggleClass("open");
});
```

also [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bGKvR/6/) here!

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, and it's short and simple. Though you should not judge me by saying that I should learn basic programming, because I know quite a bit, I just don't know crap about JS/Jquery.

Comment: @AJGreene It just seems like it. A variable with a boolean isn't much is it? ;)
Also I just realized that there is a better way... I updated it with a class. Just in case you care. ;)

Comment: I appreciate the help, and I realized that with this the class is actually not needed. I can see why you would think that I'm a newbie though, just a slow moment for me I guess. o.O